# converting from base 10 to base 31 (working only with select characters)

Tags: php, encoding, encode, base-conversion

I'd like to convert base 10 numbers to base 31

I would like to use only these characters: `23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz`

As you can see, 5 characters are excluded (i don't need these): `1 0 o l i`

The function I have now is below but of course it doesn't work. When 2 is input it outputs 4. The output for `tenTo31(2)` should be 2

```
function tenTo31($num)
{
    $out   = "";
    $alpha = "23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";

    while($num > 30)
    {
        $r = $num % 31;
        $num = floor($num / 31) - 1;
        $out = $alpha[$r] . $out;
    }

    return $alpha[$num] . $out;
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: If you put 0 or 1 in, what should you get out?

Comment: I am confused.  Going from base 10 to base 31 where you use the characters shown with translate 0 to '2', 1 to '3' and 2 to '4'.  So a mapping of 2 to '4' is expected.  Put another way, what do you expect tenTo31(0) or tenTo31(1) to output?

Comment: What should tenTo31(1) return?

Comment: I'm aware that this function does not work. That is why I'm asking for help. I put the code up just to show what I had so far. I am NOT expecting this code to do what I'm asking.

Comment: Do any of you have suggestions on the right way to do this?

Comment: The right way to do what?  Give a list of examples of what mappings you want and we can probably help you.

Comment: Like this: http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html

Comment: That's a lossy encoding format.  Are you sure you really want that?  I mean if you input I, should it give you back 1 or issue an error?

Comment: I'm still tying to find a way to reverse this.

Comment: I've decided to use VolkerK's method, which allows me to decode as well as encode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a blind guess at what you want:

```
$alpha = "yz23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwx";
```

Comment: Clever -- at least it will work for the inputs 2 through 9.  :)

Comment: Probably also the line recalculating `$num` should not have the `- 1` at the end.

Comment: Thank Greg, lucky guess :D
Also, thanks to everyone for your input and ideas.

Comment: When I use this with my original script and feed it a very number, I get an error like this:
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: -6 in C:\wamp\www\test\functions.php on line 40

Comment: You're getting intger overflow  because your number is > 2^31. Try echo (int)398985999599; - see it's negative.

Answer (score 4):

There's a built-in function for converting from one base to another, [base_convert()](http://docs.php.net/base_convert). The alphabet is fixed, but you can use [strtr()](http://docs.php.net/strtr) to replace those digits with your own.

"The output for tenTo31(2) should be 2": One possibility is to make '2' the third symbol again.

```
function tenTo31($num) {
  static $from = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
  static $to   = "yz23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwx";
  return strtr(base_convert($num, 10, 31), $from, $to);
}

for($i=0; $i<31; $i++) {
 echo $i, '=', tenTo31($i), ' | ';
 if ( 9===$i%10 ) echo "\n";
}
```

prints

```
0=y | 1=z | 2=2 | 3=3 | 4=4 | 5=5 | 6=6 | 7=7 | 8=8 | 9=9 | 
10=a | 11=b | 12=c | 13=d | 14=e | 15=f | 16=g | 17=h | 18=j | 19=k | 
20=m | 21=n | 22=p | 23=q | 24=r | 25=s | 26=t | 27=u | 28=v | 29=w | 
30=x |
```

edit:
To convert the base(31) number back to decimal you first have to reverse the translation (strtr) and then call base_convert(.., 31, 10). You can combine the conversion from and to base(31) in a single function.

```
function convert_ten_31($num, $numIsDecimal) {
  static $default = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
  static $symbols = "yz23456789abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwx";

  if ( $numIsDecimal ) {
   return strtr(base_convert($num, 10, 31), $default, $symbols);
  }
  else {
   return base_convert(strtr($num, $symbols, $default), 31, 10);
  } 
}

// testing
for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) {
 $x = convert_ten_31($i, true);
 $x = convert_ten_31($x, false);

 if ( $i!==(int)$x ) {
  var_dump($i, $x);
  die;
 }
}
echo 'done.';
```

It's also easily possible to write a function like base_convert() yourself that take the symbols as parameter and thus having one flexible function instead of tenTo30(), tenTo31(), tenTo32(), ....

Comment: This is good but is there a way to make it behave more like my original function?

In my original function: tenTo31(31) give me yy
whereas your function tenTo31(31) gives me zy

Comment: `zy` is correct. 31(dec) is 10(31), translated to your alphabet (as suggested in this thread) `zy`. `yy` would be `00`. The -1 after floor(..) in your function needs to be removed.

Comment: Ok, one more thing, how do i convert the output back to decimal?

Comment: I'm referring to your function, which I plan to use.

Comment: Also, please make a very small edit to this post so that I can vote.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the 1 and 0 characters, the first digit in your numbering system is 2 meaning 2 is the equivalent of 0 in base 10. 3 is equivalent to 1 in base 10 and 4 is equivalent to 2 in base 10.

Comment: To put it another way if you eliminated the characters abcde it would work the way you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That is why I am posting here because I can't figure out how to make the function work as I wanted it to.

Comment: You are getting the second value in your counting system.

Imagine you didn't use numbers at all, you just used abcdef so if you put in 2, you would expect to get c 0=a,1=b,2=c Ok, now lets replace abcdef with what you used as a string 23456 0=2,1=3,2=4 That's the problem, its with the way you started your number system.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you taking modules by 32? You should use %31 and /31. In base 10 we are using modules by 10, so should be in base 31. But if we forget about this, I think your logic is correct. I can't understand why 2 in base 10 is equal to 4 in base 31 using your "modified digits".

Answer (score 0):

While I'd encourage you to continue along with your algorithm for the learning exercise, consider using [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) if you just need to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping according to http://www.crockford.com/wrmg/base32.html appears to be:

```
function symbolToEncode ($num) {
    $out   = "";
    static $alpha = "0123456789ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRSTVWXYZ*~$=U";

    while ($num >= 37) {
        $r = $num % 37;
        $num = floor ($num / 37);
        $out = $out . $alpha[$r];
    }

    return $out . $alpha[$num];
}

function decodeToEncode ($str) {
  static $from = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ*~=$";
  static $to   = "0123456789ABCDEFGH1JK1MN0PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH1JK1MN0PQRSTUVWXYZ*~=$";
  return strtr ($str, $from, $to);
}
```

Though clearly the real challenge is to write a encodeToSymbol() function.  I am not really a PHP expert (my $'s in the strings probably needs to be escaped somehow -- hints?), so I will leave that to others.